# How do i properly do multiple splash screens android

Tags: java, android

I want to make two splash screens for my android app. Only the second splash screen is visible whereas the first one isn't. Is what am trying to do possible? Here is my manifest.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.app">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity1"/>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity2">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and here is my code for first splash screen

```
.........
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                Intent i = new Intent(SplashActivity1.this, 
  SplashActivity2.class);
                startActivity(i);

                // close this activity
                finish();
            }
        }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
    }
```

and second Splash Screen

```
..................
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {


            @Override
            public void run() {
            Intent i = new Intent(SplashActivity2.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

                // close this activity
                finish();
            }
        }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);

    }
```

Comment: Create a new splash activity now, instead of doing an intent to MainActivty in the first splash intent to the second splash and finally intent to MainActivity from the second splash

Comment: i did that. didnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the intent filter from splashscreen 2 activity like in below code. other things are ok.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.app">

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <activity android:name=".MainActivity"/>             
        <activity
                android:name=".SplashActivity1">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
</activity>
            <activity
                android:name=".SplashActivity2">

            </activity>
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

Comment: after doing that, my app refuses to run. tells me "Error running app, default activity not found".

Comment: There was little issue in closing tags. you can recheck the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"` should be give to only one Activity, which you want to call when app launches.

remove that from other Activities.

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity  
        android:name=".SplashActivity1">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".SplashActivity2"/>

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"/>

</application>
```

I highly recommend you first learn How to deal with [Intent_filter](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html).

Answer (score 0):

**Try with this: Make Main activity as default one and splash screen as Main launcher**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.app">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity1"/>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity2">
    </activity>
</application>
```